# success dialog box after uninstallation process

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project, custom-action

I have created a setup project in visual studio 2008. The MSI installer is working perfectly fine. Now, I wan to show a dialog box after the un-installation process showing the success of the process. I read online that it's not possible to add a custom dialog box during uninstallation process as windows installer runs the process in in Basic UI mode. But is there any way to show a dialog box via custom action? Which parameter/ flag I can use to recognize that uninstallation was successful or not? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basic UI mode or not (even on completely non-interactive / 'qn' installs) you should be able to pop a dialog via custom action. Typically, installers have a 'Finished' dialog at the end - with either success message or error message. Unfortunately these Visual Studio setup projects do not seem to support adding any custom actions. However, this is an MSI, so you could use MSI tools (Orca, InstEd) and insert your Custom Action that way..I've never done this however

Comment: @jJack Thanks for your help. Do you mean by commit custom action? can you refer me to some website or blog which explains the implementation  you mentioned?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the Commit type, however you might be on to something as Commit phase runs only after InstallFinalize success: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367991(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the Commit type, however you might be on to something as Commit phase runs only after InstallFinalize success: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367991(v=vs.85).aspx . After a little more research, it appears you CAN add custom actions to VS deployment projects. Start here maybe?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(v=vs.80).aspx